# DevExpress Winforms XtraGrid - Show groups in a single row/line

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have a grid where users group by multiple columns. The issue is, due to the way DevExpress grid displays multiple group columns, the group panel height grows with each grouped column. This is because the group panel shows grouped columns in a tree like view.

Is it possible to display all the grouped columns in a single line/row in the group panel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the [GridView's OptionsView.ShowGroupPanelColumnsAsSingleRow property](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.GridOptionsView.ShowGroupPanelColumnsAsSingleRow.property) to **True** to achieve this behavior. It is False by default.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use grammatically set group by function may be it can help you.

Try it:

gridView1.Columns["Column"].GroupIndex = 0;